# Excel 2013 VBA - setting up a list of email reciepients (TO and CC) populating Oulook email

Tags: excel, email, outlook, vba

I have set up a Userform which saves data to the Incident Details data sheet and also saves data temporarily to a worksheet called 'Email Form' and laid out like a form so that the 'email form' is copied into the body of a MS Outlook email.

This works perfectly, and with the current coding I was provided sends one email **To** 1 recipient and **CC'd** to another, but I need to send same email to multiple recipients.
I have created another sheet called ‘Email Recipient List (same workbook) because I want it to be easy to update the lists as required (none of the users would be able to edit the hardcode in VBA).
Column A has a list of TO recipients and Column B has a list of CC recipients.

I have searched and view several videos and sites, but I have been unable to workout how to extract the respective lists from the ‘Email Recipient List’ sheet  and populate the Outlook email without it affecting the existing actions. I don't want a macro button for users to click because the code opens up the Outlook email.

This is my existing code:

```
Sub log_send_reset()
'THIS OPENS OUTLOOK WITH DETAILS OF FORM

'WORKS with "Email Form"
Dim SecIncNo As String

'This bit emails the current worksheet in the body of an email as HTML
'#If 0 Then
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Sheets("Email Form").Range("A1:AB119")
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True 'ShyButterfly set this to TRUE (it was false)
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail

'This bit tells it where to send the email to, what the subject line is  etc

 .to = "246abc@company.com"

 .CC = "rep3@company2.com"
 .BCC = ""
 .Subject = Range("H6").value & " - " & "SAC" & Range("G12").value & " - " & Range("G14").value & " - " & Range("H8").value
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    'Shybutterfly changed from.Send to .Display to see what it does
    .Display
'or use .Display if you want to edit / add text before sending

End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing


ThisWorkbook.Save

'ThisWorkbook.Close

'Application.Quit


End Sub
```

[image]

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you create the Recipient lists for you.

> EmailTo = getRecipients(1)
>
> EmailCC = getRecipients(2)

```
Function getRecipients(vColumn As Variant) As String
    Dim rListColumn As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim s As String
    With Worksheets("Email Recipient List")

        Set rListColumn = .Range(.Cells(2, vColumn), .Cells(Rows.Count, vColumn).End(xlUp))
        
        For Each c In rListColumn
            s = s & c.Text & ";"
        Next

        getRecipients = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    End With
    
End Function
```

I didn't see where you would get a variable not defined error.  If getRecipients was in a private module you'd get a sub or function not defined error.

I refactored our code.  Please this in a code module by itself and run ComposeEmail.

```
    Option Explicit
    Public Sub ComposeEmail()

        ToggleEvents False

        Dim EmailTo As String, CC As String, BCC As String, Subject As String, HTMLBody As String, ShowEmail As Boolean
        Dim rng As Range
        
        ToggleEvents False

        Set rng = Sheets("Email Form").Range("A1:AB119")

        EmailTo = getRecipients(1)
        CC = getRecipients(2)
        'BCC = getRecipients(2)
        Subject = Range("H6").Value & " - " & "SAC" & Range("G12").Value & " - " & Range("G14").Value & " - " & Range("H8").Value
        HTMLBody = RangetoHTML2(rng)
        ShowEmail = True
        
        SendMail EmailTo, CC, BCC, Subject, HTMLBody, ShowEmail

        ' ThisWorkbook.Close True 'This Line save and Closes the workbook

        ToggleEvents True

    End Sub

    Function getRecipients(vColumn As Variant) As String
        Dim rListColumn As Range
        Dim c As Range
        Dim s As String
        With Worksheets("Email Recipient List")
                        
            Set rListColumn = .Range(.Cells(2, vColumn), .Cells(Rows.Count, vColumn).End(xlUp))

            For Each c In rListColumn
                s = s & c.Text & ";"
            Next

            getRecipients = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
        End With

    End Function

    Public Sub SendMail(EmailTo As String, CC As String, BCC As String, Subject As String, HTMLBody As String, ShowEmail As Boolean)
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .to = EmailTo
            .CC = CC
            .BCC = BCC
            .Subject = Subject
            .HTMLBody = HTMLBody
            
            If ShowEmail Then
                .Display
            Else
                .Send
            End If

        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    EmailCouldNotBeCreated:
        MsgBox "Email could not be created", vbCritical, "Error in Sub SendMail"
    End Sub

    Sub ToggleEvents(bEnableEvents As Boolean)
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = bEnableEvents
            .ScreenUpdating = bEnableEvents
        End With
    End Sub


    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519602%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

    Function RangetoHTML2(rng As Range)
    ' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
        Dim fso As Object
        Dim ts As Object
        Dim TempFile As String
        Dim TempWB As Workbook

        TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
     
        ' Copy the range and create a workbook to receive the data.
        rng.Copy
        Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
        With TempWB.Sheets(1)
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
            .Cells(1).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            On Error Resume Next
            .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
            .DrawingObjects.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
     
        ' Publish the sheet to an .htm file.
        With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
             SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
             Filename:=TempFile, _
             Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
             Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
             HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
            .Publish (True)
        End With
     
        ' Read all data from the .htm file into the RangetoHTML subroutine.
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
        RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
        ts.Close
        RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                              "align=left x:publishsource=")
     
        ' Close TempWB.
        TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
     
        ' Delete the htm file.
        Kill TempFile
     
        Set ts = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing
        Set TempWB = Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I added the Function to a Module and replaced the To and CC to EmailTo & EmailCC in the sub, but I cant get it to work. I get error "variable not defined".  I tried to define it by Dim EmailTo as String (etc) but did not work. I am a little confused how to do it. Please advise. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Either call `MailItem.Recipients.Add` for each recipient (it returns Recipient object, sets its `Recipient.Type` property to olTo/olCC/olBCC appropriately) to set the To/CC/BCC properties to a ";" separated list of addresses.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for your response. Sorry, but this confuses me a bit. Just how would this be set out as per my existing code above? Is this based on using @ThomasInzina function? Doesn't there need to be a definition of the variable? (I'm still trying to grasp VBA - its a slow process for me).

Comment: Yes, you will need to loop through the values in the range and call Recipients.Add for each value. Or build a string of addresses separated by ";".